# Are proprietary drivers better for battery life?

Tags: drivers, performance, battery, intel, proprietary

I have an Intel HD 4400 onboard video card. I was pondering getting the properitary linux drivers from Intel.

Will this increase battery life and performance?

Does this apply to other components as well?

Answer (score 0):

Intel drivers for are open source.
http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-010512.htm

You need to know if the distro default worse the the newest from Intel.